# NSIndexPath of UITableViewCell subview?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uibutton

Is there any was to get the NSIndexPath of a UITableViewCell's contentView subview?

In my case, I have a table view in which each row is split into 3 buttons. I can use the button tag to keep track of which column it is but I also need to know what row of the table view it is a subview of (when the user taps the button).

Because the button blocks the entire actual table view row, didSelectRowAtIndexPath is never called (which is expected), so I can't get it that way.

I have tried just [thisButton superview] but that doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I assume the button is sending its `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event message to your view controller? Then you could do something like:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
    CGPoint location = [button.superview convertPoint:button.center toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    [self doSomethingWithRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: This answer is actually a bit more what I was going for and more elegant.

Comment: Also immune to inserts/deletes/rearranging of rows, if you were so choosing to do that.

Comment: Hmm.. It seems to not be working for my third column of buttons. It is converting the touch location correctly, but on indexPathForRowAtPoint, it returns 0 for every button in the 3rd column (works for the first two columns though). Could it have something to do with being a landscape view?

Comment: Sorry, I was converting from wrong coordinate space. Since I was using the button `center`, I should have been converting from its `superview` coordinate space. I have updated the code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

One possible option is when making the cell for index path you can assign the tag to be `3 * row_number + <the tag number>`. then just divide the tag by 3 to get the row and %3 to get the button.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call button.superview. You can go straight from any subview in the tree right to the table view

### Objective-C

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCellContainingView:(UIView *)view inTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    CGPoint viewCenterRelativeToTableview = [tableView convertPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(view.bounds)) fromView:view];
    NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:viewCenterRelativeToTableview];
    return cellIndexPath
}
```

### Swift

```
func indexPathForCellContainingView(view: UIView, inTableView tableView:UITableView) -> NSIndexPath? {
    let viewCenterRelativeToTableview = tableView.convertPoint(CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(view.bounds)), fromView:view)
    return tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(viewCenterRelativeToTableview)
}
```