# UITextField subview of UITableViewCell, get indexPath of cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextfield

I have added a `UITextField` as a subview of a `UITableViewCell`.  Then I have added a `target` and `selector` so that I can know when `UIControlEventEditingChanged`.  This works great, but I would like you know the `indexPath` of the cell that the `UITextField` is in, as it could be added to any number of cells.

Is this possible?  Basically I want to find the parent view which is a `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: This works for me 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408907/nsindexpath-of-uitableviewcell-subview

hope it helps somebody..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Call `[UIView superview]` on the field to get the cell that it's in, then call `[UITableView indexPathForCell:]` on the cell to get the index path.

UPDATE: on iOS 7 you need to call superview on that view too (extra layer of views); here's a category on UITableView that should work independent of iOS version:

```
@interface UITableView (MyCoolExtension) 

- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCellContainingView:(UIView *)view;

@end

@implementation UITableView (MyCoolExtension)

- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCellContainingView:(UIView *)view {
    while (view != nil) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            return [self indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)view];
        } else {
            view = [view superview];
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Hmm, so `[UIView superview]` will return something? EDIT: Nevermind, tested it and it works.  This is perfect, very easy!

Comment: this will not work for cells which are not visible, since indexPathForCell returns nil for non visible views

Comment: True, but if the cell is currently being edited then presumably that's not a problem.

Comment: Hi.  I'm doing [self.view superview], is that correct? 

Also, can you please elaborate on how to call [UITableView indexPathForCell:] .  I need to find the indexPath in - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField

Comment: you don't need to recursively attempt to find the superview. See my answer

Answer (score 11):

Instead of recursively trying to find the superview, there's a simpler solution:

### Swift

```
func indexPathForCellContainingView(view: UIView, inTableView tableView:UITableView) -> NSIndexPath? {
    let viewCenterRelativeToTableview = tableView.convertPoint(CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(view.bounds)), fromView:view)
    return tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(viewCenterRelativeToTableview)
}
```

### Objective-C

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCellContainingView:(UIView *)view inTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    CGPoint viewCenterRelativeToTableview = [tableView convertPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(view.bounds)) fromView:view];
    NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:viewCenterRelativeToTableview];
    return cellIndexPath
}
```

I made this into a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/danielgalasko/ab78ed6359951d23d461) for the Swift hearted

Comment: Just wanted to thank you so much for putting both an ObjC and Swift solution! Your swift function works awesomely

Comment: @A_toaster so glad to hear I helped someone! Have a great day:)

Comment: Works well for visible views, not so much for views out of superview's bounds

Comment: That's because you can't access any cell outside the visible range @AntonDuzenko  that's why it returns an optional

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. It worked for me

```
   #pragma mark - Get textfield indexpath
- (NSIndexPath *)TextFieldIndexpath:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGPoint origin = textField.frame.origin;
    CGPoint point = [textField.superview convertPoint:origin toView:self.TblView];

    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.TblView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
    NSLog(@"Indexpath = %@", indexPath);
    return indexPath;
}
```

Comment: What exactly does your answer contribute that mine doesn't? :) Its almost the same code save for your variable names (PS in iOS we don't uppercase the first letter of a variable)

Comment: the code is different it uses `convertPont:toView` instead of `convertPoint:fromView`. Maybe you missed that in your arrogance. #bad

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share `@Ertebolle` code in swift -

```
extension UITableView
{
    func indexPathForCellContainingView(view1:UIView?)->NSIndexPath?
    {
        var view = view1;
        while view != nil {
            if (view?.isKindOfClass(UITableViewCell) == true)
            {
                return self.indexPathForCell(view as! UITableViewCell)!
            }
            else
            {
                view = view?.superview;
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4/5

```
func indexPathForCellContainingView(view: UIView,
                                    inTableView tableView:UITableView) -> IndexPath? {
    let viewCenterRelativeToTableview =
        tableView.convert(CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY), to: view)
    return tableView.indexPathForRow(at: viewCenterRelativeToTableview)
}
```