# Get indexPath of UITextField in UITableViewCell with Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

So, I'm building a Detail View Controller App that presents a Table with a two-part cell: the label and the Text Field.

I'm trying to retrieve the Text Field value and add it to an array.
I tried to use the "`textField.superview.superview`" technique but it didn't worked.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField!){
    var cell: UITableViewCell = textField.superview.superview
    var table: UITableView = cell.superview.superview
    let textFieldIndexPath = table.indexPathForCell(cell)
}
```

Xcode fails to build and presents that "`UIView` is not convertible to `UITableViewCell`" and "to `UITableView`".
The referring table has two sections, of four and two rows, respectively.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
added ".superview" at the second line of the function.

Comment: have you tried casting? try adding "as UITableViewCell" at the end of the .superview.superview line

Comment: iOS 7 changed the UITableViewCell hierachy, something.superview.superview no longer works. You need to use the [sender convertPoint:CGRectZero toView:self.tableView] to get root point, then go NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:rootPoint]; Of course, you need to do this using Swift code, which I don't know (just showing the algorithm here that's all).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577392/uitextfield-subview-of-uitableviewcell-get-indexpath-of-cell/27938042#27938042

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll want to cast the first and second lines in your function, like this:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField!){
    var cell: UITableViewCell = textField.superview.superview as UITableViewCell
    var table: UITableView = cell.superview as UITableView
    let textFieldIndexPath = table.indexPathForCell(cell)
}
```

superview returns a UIView, so you need to cast it to the type of view you expect.

Comment: Now it builds correctly but when the simulator runs the "cell as UITableView" the app crashes. Might you guess whats wrong?

Comment: It's probably because the cell's superview isn't a UITableView. You'll have to access the tableview differently

Comment: suggestions? im really new to this world ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110482/reference-from-uitableviewcell-to-parent-uitableview may help

Comment: Useful. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 29):

While the currently accepted answer might work, it assumes a specific view hierarchy, which is not a reliable approach since it is prone to change.

To get the `indexPath` from a `UITextField` that is inside a cell, it's much better to go with the following:

```swift
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField!){
    let pointInTable = textField.convert(textField.bounds.origin, to: self.tableView)
    let textFieldIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: pointInTable)
    ...
}
```

This will continue to work independent of eventual changes to the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 9):

Using superview and typecasting isn't a preferred aaproach. The best practice is to use delegate pattern. If you have a textField in DemoTableViewCell which you are using in DemoTableViewController make a protocol DemoTableViewCellDelegate and assign delegate of DemoTableViewCell to DemoTableViewController so that viewcontroller is notified when eiditing ends in textfield.

```
protocol DemoTableViewCellDelegate: class {
  func didEndEditing(onCell cell: DemoTableViewCell)
}

class DemoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

  weak var delegate: DemoTableViewCellDelegate?

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    textField.delegate = self
  }
}

extension DemoTableViewCell: UITextFieldDelegate {
  func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    delegate.didEndEditing(onCell: self)
  }
}

class DemoTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: DemoTableViewCell.self, for: indexPath)
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
  }

}

extension DemoTableViewController: DemoTableViewCellDelegate {
  func didEndEditing(onCell cell: DemoTableViewCell) {
    //Indexpath for the cell in which editing have ended.
    //Now do whatever you want to do with the text and indexpath.
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    let text = cell.textField.text
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `tag` property of `UITableViewCell`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UpdateTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! UpdateTableViewCell

        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.setCellData()

        return cell
}
```

now in `UITableViewCell`

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField!){
    let textFieldIndexPath = self.tag
}
```

Comment: it will always give 0 tag, It is applied if you have one `textField` in the whole table view and that will be without using the tag. Tags are only useful in button action.