# Get instance of class from `UIView`

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, instance

I'm trying to access to the instance variable that contains my `UIView`.

To be more precise, I have a custom `UITableViewCell`. Inside I have a `UIView` and I would like to access to this cell through my `UIView`. 
Basically I passed this `UIView` as parameter of another function somewhere else.

Is there any possibility to access to my cell through this `UIView` or do I have to find another way ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`UIView` will be a subview of that `UITableViewCell`. `UIView` has a property `superview` which maybe that `UITableViewCell` based on whatever view hierarchy you've established. You can also get the superview's view.

`UITableViewCell* parentCell = (UITableViewCell*)myView.superview;`

or

`= (UITableViewCell*)myView.superview.superview;`

Comment: I thought that this `superview` method was only able to access to `UIView`. That's why I directly stop searching in that way. I forgot that a `UITableViewCell` was still a view...

Comment: Yes, everything UI is a UIView.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why are do this and I think, it's a bit ugly. But you may try this category:

```
@interface UITableView (MyCoolExtension) 

- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCellContainingView:(UIView *)view;

@end

@implementation UITableView (MyCoolExtension)

- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCellContainingView:(UIView *)view {
    while (view != nil) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            return [self indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)view];
        } else {
            view = [view superview];
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

I took answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577392/uitextfield-subview-of-uitableviewcell-get-indexpath-of-cell).

Comment: Basically I have a `UITableViewCell` with a spinner. When an picture is downloading there is a spinner else there is not. I start the spinner when I try to access to this picture (even if it's store locally). I made my own cache class and this class is in charge of stoping the spinner.. In parameter I have a `UIView`. I think I'll try to add as subview of this `UIView` the spinner instead of putting it on a superview. Do you think it seems possible ?

Comment: @bobbystouket, as I understand, you have `UITableView` with `UIImageView`s in its cells. And you show `activityView` while downloading images. You may initialize your cell with `activityView` and make a callback from your cache class to your cell to remove `activityView` and set an image.

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted to do but I'm currently using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#using-asynchronous-image-downloader-independently) on my cache class. I don't know how to create such a callback from it.

Comment: My cell allows the user to show a picture in fullscreen. But the full screen variable is on my main controller. That means my cell manages my controller's `UIView`. When I put the fullscreen button, the method is called on my current cell. Can I transfer the delegation to my main controller even if my cell start this action ?

Comment: @bobbystouket, of course yes! You need to create delegate in you custom cell class. Call delegate's method from some action in your custom cell. And realize delegate's method in main controller.

Comment: That means I need a delegate method for my cache class implemented on my cell with another delegate for my custom cell implemented on my main controller. Is it correct ? It seems to be a bit big as modifications I want to be sure before. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Thank for the tip. I added the solution I used.